# How can I have a view only custom field of type "Link" be clickable in a profile?

Tags: profile

I have a custom field of type "Link" presented as View Only in a public profile (I have several of these field types in the same profile).

Frustration is that the Link isn't clickable, so the user has to copy and paste the URL instead of being able to click on it.

I'm using Joomla 3.8 and civiCRM 5.10.1

Any suggestions how I can make these clickable?

[image]